# trying to open Tshark process and start capturing

Tags: c#, wireshark

i am trying to open Tshark process and start capturing but my process start and immediate close so my pcap file is in size of zero and i don't know why.

```
string path = "-i 1 -s 65535 -w \\192.168.0.1\captures\myFile.pcap";";
public string _tshark = @"C:\Program Files (x86)\Wireshark\tshark.exe";


        public void startCapture(string path)
        {
            ProcessStartInfo ps = new ProcessStartInfo();
            ps.FileName = _tshark;
            ps.CreateNoWindow = true;
            ps.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
            ps.UseShellExecute = false;
            ps.CreateNoWindow = true; 
            ps.Arguments = path;
            Process process = new Process();
            process.StartInfo = ps;
            process.Start();

        }
```

Comment: Are you wanting to capture a specific number of packets before shutting it down?

Comment: A copy+paste of your method works fine absolutely fine for me - tshark is launched in the background, and my capture file fills for ever (until I kill the process with Task Manager). The only difference was the `path` variable, I added a leading `@` (like you have with `_tshark`).